# Why does the value of this array change when passed into a function as an argument?

Tags: python, arrays, function

I'm having a problem where when I pass an array into a function, the original value of the array is changed. My example below should clarify what I mean.

So if I have the falling example:

```
def swap(array):
    while True:
        noChange = True
        for i in range(len(array) - 1):
            if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
                array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
                noChange = False
        if noChange:
            return array

def baseline(array):
    array = sorted(array)
    return array

array = [20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
sortedArray = swap(array)
print array # Result: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
array = [20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
sortedArray = baseline(array)
print array # Result: [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

From above, you can see that for some reason, `array` has been changed when the function called `swap` is run but when I run `baseline`. In the function called `swap`, I've tried re-naming all instances of `array` to `localArray` to see if it made a difference but I'm still having the same problem.

I'm sure this is something very obvious that I've over looked but would somebody be able to explain why this is happening?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen when I print `array` for the first time it should't have changed from the value that I first defined it as, should it? That is the part that I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass the list `array` to a function, the argument reference to the same list object, if it's modified inside the function, the original list is modifed as well.

If this is not what you want, copy the list in the beginning of the function:

```
def swap(array):
    array = array[:]
    # ...
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! What is the name of the syntax `[:]` so I can search and learn about what it does? Also, I must be wrong, but why was this not happening to the function called `baseline` and also, shouldn't this not have happened when I changed the name of `array` inside the function `swap`?

Comment: List Slicing is the name. Check it out here - https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html .Important thing to note is slicing an array returns a shallow copy to the list.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a list to a function, you are passing the reference to it, hence if you change the list inside the function it will also get changed, you can send a shallow copy of the list (as the list only contains integers) as the argument, so that it does not get changed.

When calling the function do -

```
import copy
sortedArray = swap(copy.copy(array))
```

---

Another way to do it would be to copy the array inside your function, Example -

```
import copy
def swap(array):
    array = copy.copy(array)
```

---

When your list contains references to other mutable objects, you should use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function (If you will be making changes inside the objects, but you do not want the same changes to reflect to the objects in the original list).